# Alien possessing a man in a care facility

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I'm looking for the name of a live-action movie I watched maybe 15-20 years ago. It takes place in a care facility (likely a psychiatric hospital, given what I remember of the plot, but it's possible it was an elderly care facility). One of the patients, the main character, claims he is an alien that has possessed the body of a man. This is naturally doubted by most of the staff. Yet he does display some superhuman abilities, like being able to see ultraviolet/infrared light (don't remember which).

I also think there is a scene where they put him under physical stress, and his pulse goes very high. One of the staff that is more open to the idea that the alien is real says it would be dangerous if he were a normal human.

The movie ends with the alien going home, and taking one of the other patients with him. I think he had the other residents write letters to decide which one he was going to bring. And all they can find of the other patient is that letter.

Maybe the alien said he travelled to and from Earth on a beam of light. I also think he said something to the effect of the traffic on his home planet being packed, and he therefore only had a single pre-allotted time window to return, and if he didn't go back when he did, he would be unable to get back at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this ***[K-PAX](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0272152/)*** (2001)...?

It's been over a decade since I watched the film, but it stars Kevin Spacey as a patient in a mental hospital claiming to be an alien named 'prot' from another star system, and the [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-PAX_(film)) below confirms most of the other details you mentioned, such as prot being able to see ultraviolet light and apparently leaving at the end with another patient.

> After claiming he is an extraterrestrial from the planet 'K-PAX', 1,000 light years away in the Lyra constellation, prot (not capitalized and pronounced with a long O, rhyming with boat) is committed to the Psychiatric Institute of Manhattan. There, psychiatrist Dr. Mark Powell attempts to cure him of his apparent delusions. However, prot is unwavering in his ability to provide cogent answers to questions about himself, K-PAX, and its civilizations. His medical examination only reinforces his story, as **prot can see ultraviolet light** and he is completely resistant to the effects of Thorazine. Powell introduces him to a group of astrophysicists who are befuddled when prot displays a highly detailed level of knowledge about his claimed star system that was unknown to them.
>
> prot also wins over the other patients at the Institute, each of whom believes unquestioningly that he is indeed from K-PAX. **prot, who claims to have journeyed to Earth by means of "faster-than-light travel," explains that he can take one person with him when he returns.** Thereafter, most of the patients at the Institute ask prot to take them with him.
>
> Upon learning that many of his patients expect to leave Earth on July 27, Powell confronts prot, who explains that it is a predetermined date.
>
> [...]
>
> **On July 27 as the hospital staff watch, the camera in prot's room cuts to static at the precise time prot said he would leave Earth. Powell finds Porter lying on the floor in his room, catatonic, prot having apparently left Porter's body for the light travel back to K-PAX. As Robert is being wheeled out of the room, the other patients do not recognize him as prot and say that prot has gone. In addition, one of the patients is missing: Bess, a woman who had remained mute since her home was destroyed in a fire and who had been among the patients that asked to go to K-PAX with prot. She is never found.** The other patients believe that prot has taken her to K-PAX. Powell continues to take care of the catatonic Porter and tells him about how the patients he helped have gone on to live normal lives again, but Robert does not respond. Powell is left with no absolute answer as to whether prot was in fact an alien entity or just a coping mechanism of the traumatized Porter, but seems far from convinced that Porter's behavior was a delusion.

Comment: This looks precisely right. Thank you.